# another way to implement a timer in c#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I have to run a function every n minutes in a windows service. When finished, start again. If the function has started it can't start again until finished. Initially I had this idea:

```
void function()
{
  while(true)
  {
    if(!is_running)
    {
      function_to_be_repeated();
      is_running = false;
    }
    else
    {
      Thread.Sleep(some_time); // wait to start again
    }
  }
}
```

Then I found this http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx :

```
 bool running = false;

 static void Main()
  {
    // First interval = 5000ms; subsequent intervals = 1000ms
    Timer tmr = new Timer (function_to_be_repeated, "...", 5000, 1000);
    Console.ReadLine();    
    tmr.Dispose();         // This both stops the timer and cleans up.
  }

  static void function_to_be_repeated(object data)
  {
      if(!running)
      {
        running = true;
        // do some stuff...

        running = false;
      }

  }
```

But it stop when I press Enter

Is there another way to implement it better?

Comment: "But it stop when I press Enter" - Yes, that's what the code does. Now did you have a question?

Comment: Rather than using `Thread.Sleep` I tend to use the `AutoResetEvent` for timers and it has worked fairly well. Whether it is the suggested solution or not I cannot say but it provides what feels like a lighter solution for me.

Comment: There are a bunch of different classes in .NET named `Timer` (in different namespaces).  Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no completely sure what the question is as you mention a windows service and an Enter key ending your app, then you mention a better implementation.

Firstly if you are running it in a console and don't want the enter key to kill it you can do something like

```
do
{

}
while (!Console.ReadLine().Equals("exit",
                                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
       );
```

Instead of

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

This means your console will only end when you type in exit and press enter, or if you close the program by pressing the x button or killing the process.

As for better implementation, I'm not sure if this is the best practice but this is how I would do it, using a polled thread implementation:

```
class Poll : IDisposable
{
    private TimeSpan polledSpan;
    WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[2];
    ManualResetEvent exit = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    Thread thread;
    public Poll(int polledTime)
    {
        polledSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, polledTime);
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start));
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void Start()
    {            
        AutoResetEvent reset = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        handles[0] = reset;
        handles[1] = exit;
        bool run = true;
        while (run)
        {                
            int result = WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles, 
                                           (int)polledSpan.TotalMilliseconds, 
                                           false);

            switch(result)
            {
                case WaitHandle.WaitTimeout:
                    run = StuffToDo();
                    break;
                case 1:
                case 0:
                    run = false;
                    break;
            }                
        }            
    }

    private bool StuffToDo()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        exit.Set();
        if (thread != null)
        {
            thread.Join(10000);
        }
        exit = null;
        handles = null;
    }
}
```

and in the main method

```
Poll p = new Poll(1);
do
{

}
while (!Console.ReadLine().Equals("exit",
                                  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
p.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above is probably run in a console application, that's why it exists after you press  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (more precisely, this is because of `Console.Readline()`).

However, you also mentioned that you need this in a Windows Service.

In a Windows Service you would typically override the `OnStart()` and `OnStop()` methods of `ServiceBase`. In your case, the service code would look like this:

```
private Timer tmr;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    tmr = new Timer (function_to_be_repeated, "...", 5000, 1000);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    tmr.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is you are having problems with but here is an example of using a timer that will actually protect itself from running in parallell with itself (which System.Threading.Timer doesn't do by default).

Also if you want to run it in a windows service just move the creation of the timer to the start method and disposing to stop and keep the timer instance around in a property.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timeBetweenTicks = (long) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds;
        System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
        Action onTick = () =>
            {
                timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                try
                {
                    //Work on tick goes here
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                }
                finally
                {
                    timer.Change(timeBetweenTicks, timeBetweenTicks);
                }
            };
        using (timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => onTick(), null, 0, timeBetweenTicks))
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you want the time to the next tick to be influenced by how long the current one took you will need to add some timing and change the code in "finally".